# Waypoints - Trigger function for THIS element and not others with same class name

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to have an animation play every time a class is in view. I'm using Waypoints and the website is horizontal scrolling. The code I have fades out the class photo. I want it to trigger on each individual photo when it comes into view. Currently, when the first photo is in view, it triggers all of the photos to fade out.

Not sure how to write it so only one at a time happens.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName('photo'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        $(this.element).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 100);
    },
    context: document.getElementsByClassName('horizontal_scroll'),
    horizontal: true,
    offset: '50%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several different iterations I got it working with this:

```
$(".photo_wide").waypoint(function(e) {
    $(this.element).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 100);
    }, {
    context: document.getElementsByClassName('horizontal_scroll'),
    horizontal: true,
    offset: "50%"
});
```